# Sorting a vector of class pointers based on two attributes?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, conditional-statements

I am trying to sort my vector of class pointers `vector <Building*> company`. Below is my code

```
sort(company.begin(), company.end(), [] (Building* lhs, Building* rhs)
{
    return (lhs->getCompanyName() > rhs->getCompanyName() && lhs->height() > rhs->height());
});
```

I am trying to sort based on two attributes in the class called `getCompanyName()` and `height()`. `getCompanyName` is to be alphabetically order from A to Z while `height` is to sorted in descending order.

The above sorting do not work.

However, if I split the two conditions up into the two below:

```
sort(company.begin(), company.end(), [] (Building* lhs, Building* rhs)
{
    return lhs->getCompanyName() > rhs->getCompanyName();
}); 

sort(company.begin(), company.end(), [] (Building* lhs, Building* rhs)
{
    return lhs->height() > rhs->height();
});
```

The vector will sort correctly but only based on one attribute.

Is there something wrong with my 2 attributes sorting code?

Edit:

`getCompanyName()` will be sorted first based on A-Z.

Only after `getCompanyName()` is sorted then `height()` will be sorted based on descending order.

An example of the sorted expected output:

```
Company Name: AQA
Height: 300

Company Name: AFE
Height: 200

Company Name: BAC
Height: 600

Company Name: BFE
Height: 100

Company Name: CJE
Height: 1200
```

Comment: How do you define the order used for sorting? For example, which should come earlier, `getCompanyName = aaa, height = 100` or `getCompanyName = bbb, height = 200`?

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks, I have edited my post further to clarify your points.

Comment: Your comparison doesn't satisfy the requirements of a strict weak ordering, and therefore your program exhibits undefined behavior. In particular, the equivalence relation induced by the comparison is not transitive: `{"b", 3}` is equivalent to `{"c", 1}`, which is equivalent to `{"a", 2}`, but `{"b", 3}` is not equivalent to `{"a", 2}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort *first* by increasing values of `getCompanyName()` and *then* by decreasing values of `height()`, your predicate needs to be:

```
sort(company.begin(), company.end(), [] (Building* lhs, Building* rhs)
{
    return lhs->getCompanyName() < rhs->getCompanyName()    // increasing getCompanyName()
        || (lhs->getCompanyName() == rhs->getCompanyName()  // if equal getCompanyName() 
            &&  lhs->height() > rhs->height());             // then decreasing height()
});
```

Comment: I didn't expect that I need to do an equal comparison in the second sorting for the `getCompanyName()`. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: In your question you said "Only after getCompanyName() is sorted then height() will be sorted based on descending order.". That's basically what this code is doing :)

Answer (score 2):

The typical pattern is:

```
return 
(lhs->getCompanyName() > rhs->getCompanyName()) || 
(lhs->getCompanyName() == rhs->getCompanyName() &&
    lhs->height() > rhs->height());
```

Which is: sort by name first, then by height if names are the same.